# jQuery Mobile dynamic content -cannot select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working with jQuery Mobile in a google web app and just having some issues selecting a tag. More specifically, I have content that is loaded from an external source so need to have a loading page initially. Once the external source is available I then update the page with the content using jQuery. Included in this content is an input tag. The issue is when I update the page, I cannot then cannot find the value of this input tag.

Here is my code below:
(intial html - Before content is loaded)

```
       <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
          <div id="googleList" >
              <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" >
                 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-6a" id="checkbox-1-a">
                 <label for="checkbox-v-6a">Loading . . . </label>
             </fieldset>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Here is my jQuery to update the code above when the new content comes in:

```
function showTaskList(tasks)
{
   //Generate HTML
   var htmlToInsert = "<fieldset data-role=\"controlgroup\" data-mini=\"true\" >";


   for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++)
   {

      htmlToInsert += "<input type=\"checkbox\" data-id=\"" + tasks[i][1] + "\" name=\"checkbox-" + i + "-a\" id=\"checkbox-" + i + "-a\" class=\"custom taskCheckBox\" ";
      if(tasks[i][2] != undefined)
         htmlToInsert += "checked=\"checked\"";
      htmlToInsert += " />";
      htmlToInsert += "<input id=\"currency-controlgroup1\" data-id=\"" + tasks[i][1] + "\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + tasks[i][0] + "\" data-wrapper-class=\"controlgroup-textinput ui-btn\" class=\"taskinputBox\">";
   }

   //Insert HTML into site
   $("#googleList").html(htmlToInsert + "</fieldset>");

   //Refresh List
   $("#googleList").trigger("create");
}
```

Here is my code to get the input tag value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function processTaskList()
    {
       console.log("Test");
       $(document).on('click', '.taskCheckBox', function (event, ui) {
          var checkBoxId = $(this).data("data-id");
          console.log("CheckBox:" + checkBoxId );
       });
    }
});
```

CheckBoxId keeps coming back undefined when I click on one of the checkboxes. I want to be able to read the data-id value. I'm not sure how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$(this).data("data-id");` should be `$(this).data("id");`

Comment: I suspect `var checkBoxId = $(this).data("data-id");` is the problem. Did you triend `var checkBoxId = $(this).attr("id");`...

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. Still same result. My guess is that it is caused by the content dynamically being added, although I'm not sure of a solution

Comment: Then try `$(this).prop("data-id");`

Comment: I don't think the last snippet of code respect the best practice in writing js code (function expression inside callback function), I am interested an expert come here and enlight us on this matter

Comment: show us the code that calls `showTaskList` function

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is now solved. I had the function call inside document.ready not the function itself. 
showTaskList is called in document.ready to and looks like:
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showTaskList).getTaskList();

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code below again, and it works - Thanks for your help

```
$(document).on('click', '.taskCheckBox', function (event, ui) {
  var checkBoxId = $(this).data("id");
  console.log("CheckBox:" + checkBoxId );
```

});